# Can I use the global application menu with AWN?

Tags: 10.10, appmenu, awn

Is it possible to use the Global/Application menu GNOME applet with AWN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There has been [some](https://bugs.launchpad.net/awn-extras/+bug/707281) demand for one earlier this year.